# (e)def and BibLaTeX

Tags: macros, biblatex

I'm trying to understand why the following code does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\def\col{\begin{english}:\end{english}}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{library.bib}
@article{Bara2006,
  author = {Bara, Judith},
  title = {{English Citation: entry}},
  year = {2006},
  journal = {Journal of Space},
  pages = {20\col1--20\col12},
}
@article{Baranov2001,
  author = {Jacques, Paul},
  title = {{Citation française : espace}},
  year = {2001},
  journal = {Comptes Rendus sur les Espaces},
  pages = {20:1--20:12},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
    inseries = {dans},
    in = {dans}
}
\begin{document}
\textsc{url:} www. \\
\begin{french}
\textsc{url:} www. \\
\end{french}
\textsc{url:} www. \\
\textsc{url\col} www. \\
C'est un essai. \parencite{Bara2006,Baranov2001}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I comment the line `\printbibliography`, everything runs as expected.

Comment: Your `\edef\col{...}` is no different from `\def\col{\begin{english}:\end{english}}`

Comment: I switched to `\def`, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define `\col` as a character that's not influenced by the interchar token state; you also want that the English citation is typeset using English rules, that's obtained by setting the `hyphenation` field.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newcommand\col{\mbox{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0 :}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bara2006,
  author = {Bara, Judith},
  title = {{English Citation: entry}},
  year = {2006},
  journal = {Journal of Space},
  pages = {20\col1--20\col12},
  hyphenation={english},
}
@article{Baranov2001,
  author = {Jacques, Paul},
  title = {{Citation française : espace}},
  year = {2001},
  journal = {Comptes Rendus sur les Espaces},
  pages = {20\col1--20\col12},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
    inseries = {dans},
    in = {dans}
}
\begin{document}
\textsc{url:} www. \\
\begin{french}
\textsc{url:} www. \\
\end{french}
\textsc{url:} www. \\
\textsc{url\col} www. \\
C'est un essai. \parencite{Bara2006,Baranov2001}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this answer is that here, the bibliography is typeset in French, and so `In:` should also read `Dans :`.

Comment: @BigDawg Then don't use `hyphenation={english}`.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. If I simply do this, now an  English sentence `English Citation: entry`, is typeset in French. What I would like is `English Citation: entry". Dans :`

Comment: @BigDawg Catch 22. Use `English Citation\col\ entry` in the `.bib` file. When I say that I dislike French rules for punctuation I know why.